# Is there a way to get the iframe dom element from window.frames[0]

Tags: javascript, iframe

I always thought (when you have several iframes), that `window.frames[0]` represents the DOM element of the first iframe.

But according to the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/window/frames), this isn't true:

> Each item in the window.frames pseudo-array represents the window object
>       corresponding to the given 's or 's content, not the (i)frame 
>       DOM element (i.e., `window.frames[ 0 ]` is the same thing as 
>       `document.getElementsByTagName( "iframe" )[ 0 ].contentWindow)`.

Is there a way in JavaScript to get from `window.frames[0]` to the DOM element of the iframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`frameElement` will return the DOM element in which the iframe is embedded. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement

For example:

```
var iframeElem = window.frames[0].frameElement
```

Following, this should validate:

```
window.frames[0].frameElement.ownerDocument.defaultView.frames[0] == frames[0]
```